# Iterating over member variables in Java

Tags: java, oop, variables, iterator, hashmap

I have several situations where a class consists of an arbitrary (but fixed) number of variables of differing types and wish to iterate over those variables as well as use their names in code.  Is there a smarter way to do this than to retype each variable name in each function?

My initial thought is to use a HashMap to store the local variables but that seems inefficient and doesn't handle multiple types.

Code below is simulated to shorten the required reading, but typically its more than 3 variables:

```
class Widget implements Parcelable {
    String name, code;
    Long price;

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(code);
        dest.writeLong(price);
    }

    public Widget(Parcel o) {
        name = o.name;
        code = o.code;
        price = o.price;
    }

    public String getXML() {
        return "<Widget><name>"+name+"</name><code>"+code
              +"</code><price>"+price+"</price></Widget>";
    }
}
```

Instead, I'd prefer to do something like (pseudo-code):

```
public Widget(Parcel o) {
    for (Map<Name,Data> item: o.getMap()) {
        this.setValue(Name, Data);
    }
}
public String getXML() {
    StringBuilder XML = new StringBuilder();
    XML.append("<Widget>");
    for (Map<Name,Data> item: o.getMap()) {
        XML.append("<"+Name+">" + Data + "</"+Name+">");
    }
    XML.append("</Widget>");
    return XML.toString();
}
```

I keep thinking there must be a pattern for doing this type of thing, but maybe its just my Python history kicking at my Java experience.

Update: this is not about solely fetching XML from member variables, but about looping through member variables in multiple member functions.  It would appear that Java's reflection features were missing from my repertoire.

My new smaller constructor makes me glad to have learned something useful, and looks like:

```
public Widget(Widget other) {
    for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (f.getName() == "TAG") {
            continue;
        }
        f.set(this, f.get(other));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally, if you so much of variables in your class, you should move the related one in a ValueObject, and use it's reference in your class.

Comment: Since you are accessing *member* variables (not local variables like your original title stated), you can use reflection to access them. Check out the Reflection API and tutorials for more details. Alternatively you can refactor these values to another class and use either inheritance or composition to reuse code.

Comment: I would suggest using Jackson for XML building. You won't have to deal with manual building of XML at all.

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky: why Jackson and not JAXB?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this is my personal preference. IMO, it's simpler in use. Also it's used widely.

Comment: Thanks @Code-Guru for the comment and edit.  cf. comments on Meriton's answer below.

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky I don't typically manually build XML but typing in proper API references in the example was just too much effort and I hoped everyone here would understand what I was getting at either way.  Loving the API suggestions though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is usually solved with reflection:

```
for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    String name = f.getName();
    String value = f.get(this);
}
```

However, for writing to / reading from XML, you probably want to use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: w.r.t. XML I intentionally wrote it out as a string to avoid specific APIs and give any example at all that I could type quickly.

Comment: +1 while I spend some time reading up on Java reflection, looks nearly perfect ... although it may take some time to absorb properly.

Comment: I can manage most of the situations where I have numerous variables listed out in an object with this method, except populating from a SQLite cursor so far.  There's no generic Cursor.getObject(...) to then cast for f.set(...);  Perhaps another question is necessary.

Comment: erm, for mapping database rows, I'd point you to [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) ...

Comment: w.r.t. JPA, the question was generic but implementation is Android-specific for me although http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml looks interesting.

Comment: Not sure why I had to `f.get(object)` instead of `f.getValue(...)`, but worked.

Comment: Fixed. I had typed this from memory, and promptly misremembered the method name.

Answer (score 3):

Use Jackson:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

Serialization is done very similar to JSON serialization: all that needs to change is ObjectMapper instance to use:

```
// Important: create XmlMapper; it will use proper factories, workarounds
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValue(new Simple());
```

and with POJO like:

```
public class Simple {
    public int x = 1;
    public int y = 2;
}
```

you would get something like:

```
<Simple>
  <x>1</x>
  <y>2</y>
</Simple>
```

(except that by default output is not indented: you can enabled indentation using standard Jackson mechanisms)

Deserializing POJOs from XML
Similar to serialization, deserialization is not very different from JSON deserialization:

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Simple value = xmlMapper
   .readValue("<Simple><x>1</x><y>2</y></Simple>", Simple.class);
```

P.S. You can also use reflection for that and iterate via all declared fields using `Class.getDeclaredFields()`. But from my experience one rarely has to do that. There is a lot of 3rd party open-source libraries for different purposes and usually it's a better solution just to use them (e.g. Jackson in this particular case)

Comment: This isn't about simply getting XML out of variables, its about iterating through local variables over and over in multiple class functions.

Answer (score 2):

If there are a number of classes whose code follows the same pattern, I would write a code generator to generate the Java source code from a definition file of some kind. Then you can have your generator create simple code like your first example, that is easier to read and understand (than using a generic map or reflection or something). The definition file becomes your "official" source of the fields of each kind of object.

Since you're already familiar with Python, your definition file could simply be built right in to a Python script to create the source code. For example:

```
Objects = {
    "Widget": [
        (TYPE_STRING, "name"),
        (TYPE_STRING, "code"),
        (TYPE_LONG, "price"),
    ],
    # ...
}
```

With appropriate definitions of `TYPE_STRING` and so on, it should be straightforward to write some code that generates Java source from this.

Comment: I love this as a hack, but it feels like a hack.  I suspect reflection as suggested by @meriton will best serve my purposes.  I promise to post a working example if and when I find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [**XStream**](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) is simplest framework to do this. Refer the [**Two minute tutorial**](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html), you will get an idea.

It is as simple as creating a mapping class e.g. `Widget` with all member attributes and possible nesting of objects then calling:

```
   XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
   String xml = xstream.toXML(widgetObject);  // <-- Get XML String from object

   Widget widget = (Widget)xstream.fromXML(xml); //<-- Get object from XML
```